# How can I generalize these two coroutines so I only use one? (Input a boolean into the parameters and set from within)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on some script and I have the following two coroutines:

```
private IEnumerator blockTimer(float duration)
{
    blocking = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    blocking = false;

    movementCooldown = true;
    sprite.color = Color.green;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    movementCooldown = false;

    sprite.color = Color.white;

    yield return null;
}
private IEnumerator dashTimer(float duration)
{
    dashing = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    dashing = false;

    movementCooldown = true;
    sprite.color = Color.green;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    movementCooldown = false;

    sprite.color = Color.white;

    yield return null;
}
```

They are called in my update function upon different inputs:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (dashing || blocking || movementCooldown) return;
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Dash") & (movementX!=0||movementY!=0))
    {
        sprite.color = Color.red;
        StartCoroutine(dashTimer(dashTime));
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Block"))
    {
        sprite.color = Color.blue;
        StartCoroutine(blockTimer(blockTime));
        
    }
}
```

Obviously, these two coroutines are very similar. I've been playing around with some different ways to generalize them. I just can't figure out how I'm meant to pass a bool as a parameter into one general coroutine and set it from within. I can set the booleans by pointing directly to them but how do I make it so I can call on a parameter bool and update it during the coroutine? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a call back function as a parameter, like this :

```
private IEnumerator GenericTimer(float duration, Func<bool, bool> callback)
    {
        callback(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        callback(false);

        movementCooldown = true;
        sprite.color = Color.green;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        movementCooldown = false;

        sprite.color = Color.white;
    }
```

And then you just make a lambda that assign this value to either blocking or dashing variables:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (dashing || blocking || movementCooldown) return;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Dash") & (movementX!=0||movementY!=0))
        {
            sprite.color = Color.red;
            StartCoroutine(GenericTimer(dashTime, (bool value) => dashing = value));
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Block"))
        {
            sprite.color = Color.blue;
            StartCoroutine(GenericTimer(blockTime, (bool value) => blocking = value));
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay awesome - and I know it's probably a dumb question but what does the "Func<>" function look like generally?